# how to split lines of the output of subprocess in Flask webapp

Tags: python, flask

How to split the output of a script and display in flask webapp ?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
import subprocess
import os
import datetime
import time
app = Flask(__name__)

def api():
    cmd = ["/usr/dummy.ksh"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)                    
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    return stdout
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('subprocess.html', subprocess_output=api())


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

"I expect on the flask app to see the stdout of the dummy script line by line. However, im getting all the output in a single string.

**Desired output in flask web page:**

```
Script completed step 1
script completed step 2
all done...exiting
```

**Current output in flask web page:**

```
Script completed step 1 script completed step 2 all done...exiting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can wrap the output in `<pre>...</pre>` tags.
2. You can add HTML line breaks to your output, for example:

   `return "<br/>".join(stdout.splitlines())`

Comment: Can you modify my code ans show it, should i make this change on my return statement ? or it needs to be added to HTML ?

Comment: The first method is for your template, and the second is just a change to your `return` statement.

Comment: Modified the HTML and it worked . Added the following                                     <pre>{{ subprocess_output }}</pre>